# Alembic toggling multiple database using environment variables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I have a question about alembic `multidb` template or using alembic for multiple database in general.

Our project has your usual three levels of database (development, testing, production). Depending on which level of database and whether it runs via Airflow or not, the URL for each database will be different. I'd like to use a `.env` file to store the URLs and credentials and run the migration using a command like:

`alembic -x db=development airflow=False upgrade head`

What should I do to achieve this? Thank you in advance for any assitance!